# How to regularly check state of property?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a video player in QT C++. I am using a progress bar. I am using these line to move forward the progress bar

`connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::durationChanged,bar,&QProgressBar::setMaximum);   connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::positionChanged,bar,&QProgressBar::setValue);`

Now I want to this step: When my `bar` (my progress bar variable) has a value of greater than 10, it should mute the video using my `setVol(0)` method and revive the video audio again when value is greater than 30 using `setVol(defaultVol);`

How can I do what I am doing.

Here's my whole code: [Link](https://github.com/ay2306/Censored-Video-Player/blob/master/mainwindow.cpp)

Comment: What's bar? You need to include what you've tried

Comment: Sorry, let me write in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the valueChanged signal of the QProgressBar:

```
connect(bar, &QProgressBar::valueChanged, [this](int value){
    if(value > 10 && value < 30)
        player->setVolume(0);
    else
        player->setVolume(defaultVol);
});
```